# Does Azure App Service running Asp.Net Core 3.1 in a Linux docker container support User Assigned Managed Identity?

Tags: azure, docker, authentication, asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

I have an Asp.Net Core 3.1 application that reads its configuration from a Key Vault using the following code:

```
var keyVaultEndpoint = builtConfig["ProductKeyVaultUri"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultEndpoint))
{
    var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
    var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
        new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
            azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
    config.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, keyVaultClient,
        new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());
}
```

It uses the most recent version of the `Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication` package to date - 1.4.0

The application is deployed to an Azure App Service with a System Managed Identity (MI for short), which can read secrets from the relevant Key Vault. It works.

Indeed when I remove the System MI from the Key Vault access policy and restart the App Service, I get this:

```
Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException: Access denied. Caller was not found on any access policy.
Caller: appid=6f215b10-33a1-4e5d-b3b7-20e8f3d3b587;oid=3d6af26c-af56-4cef-a832-41c2303a8cbe;numgroups=0;iss=https://sts.windows.net/2...b/
Vault: a...v;location=eastus2
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.GetSecretsWithHttpMessagesAsync(String vaultBaseUrl, Nullable`1 maxresults, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.GetSecretsAsync(IKeyVaultClient operations, String vaultBaseUrl, Nullable`1 maxresults, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.LoadAsync()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at Gateway.Program.Main(String[] args)
/opt/startup/init_container.sh: line 20:    10 Aborted                 (core dumped) dotnet Gateway.dll
```

(I scrubbed the tenantId and the key vault name)

It gives us the AppId (6f215b10-33a1-4e5d-b3b7-20e8f3d3b587) and the ObjectId (3d6af26c-af56-4cef-a832-41c2303a8cbe) which indeed match the System MI.

So far so good.

Now, I replace the System MI with a User Assigned MI, which has the access to the secrets in the same KV. However, restarting the App Service does not yield any good. The web app fails to read the secrets from the Key Vault which aborts the start of the container. Here is what docker logs tell me:

```
Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProviderException: Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/2...b. Exception Message: Tried the following 3 methods to get an access token, but none of them worked.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/2...b. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Access token could not be acquired. Received a non-retryable error. MSI ResponseCode: BadRequest, Response: {"statusCode":400,"message":"Unable to load requested managed identity.","correlationId":"1b0ee635-0805-4438-8ae8-747e9f6dd7c2"}
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/2...b. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Visual Studio. Access token could not be acquired. Environment variable LOCALAPPDATA not set.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://vault.azure.net, Authority: https://login.windows.net/2...b. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Azure CLI. Access token could not be acquired. /bin/bash: az: No such file or directory


   at Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider.GetAuthResultAsyncImpl(String resource, String authority, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.AzureServiceTokenProvider.<get_KeyVaultTokenCallback>b__8_0(String authority, String resource, String scope)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential.PostAuthenticate(HttpResponseMessage response)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultCredential.ProcessHttpRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClient.GetSecretsWithHttpMessagesAsync(String vaultBaseUrl, Nullable`1 maxresults, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.KeyVaultClientExtensions.GetSecretsAsync(IKeyVaultClient operations, String vaultBaseUrl, Nullable`1 maxresults, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.LoadAsync()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault.AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at Gateway.Program.Main(String[] args)
/opt/startup/init_container.sh: line 20:    10 Aborted                 (core dumped) dotnet Gateway.dll
```

From which I conclude that the docker must be told explicitly the name of the User Assigned MI. It kind of makes sense, because an App Service may have many User Assigned MIs, but only one System MI.

So, the question is - can we use User Assigned MI at all in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be that you are not telling `AzureServiceTokenProvider` the id of the user-assigned MI.

Here in the docs you can see samples of the connection string syntax: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/service-to-service-authentication#connection-string-support.

For your case, specify a connection string like:

> RunAs=App;AppId={ClientId of user-assigned identity}

And use that as a constructor argument for the token provider.
By default the provider tries only system-assigned MI.

Comment: I will test it and let you know.

Comment: I'm not sure if this ever worked, but it definitely does not work now. The above documentation needs to be updated.